# Automap value of Key in Ienumerable<T> to flat string[]

Tags: arrays, .net, automapper, ienumerable

I'm receiving data from an API call that I need to flatten.  The data is stored in a Ienumerable inside another object.  Below is an example of my incoming data format.

```
class Incoming 
{
   public string Something { get; set; }
   public string SomethingElse { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Service> Service1 { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Service> Service2 { get; set; }
}
```

```
class Service
{
   public string One { get; set; }
   public string Two { get; set; }
   public string ServiceName { get; set}
}
```

I need to map the serviceNames to  a string[] in another object.

```
class outgoing
{
   public string Something { get; set; }
   public string SomethingElse { get; set; }
   public string[] Service1 { get; set; }
   public string[] Service2 { get; set }
}
```

So if my incoming data's Service1 has a value of

```
{ 
Something: "A", 
SomethingElse "B", 
Service1: [
{ One: one, Two: two, ServiceName: "NameOne" },
{ One: one, Two: two, ServiceName: "NameTwo" },
{ One: one, Two: two, ServiceName: "NameThree" } 
]
```

I'd like the response to look like:

```
Something: "A",
SomethingElse: "B",
Service1: {"NameOne", "NameTwo", "NameThree"}
```

I've tried using Construct Using

```
.ConstructUsing(
   x => new string[] { x.ServiceName}
);

But the results show an array of types rather then values
  "Service1": [
     "Service",
     "Service",
     "Service"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `.MapFrom()` like this:

```
 CreateMap<Incoming, outgoing>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Service1,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(
                               src => src.Service1.Select(
                                             service => service.ServiceName)
                        )
            );
```

**BONUS** (answering the question from the comment, not sure if it will work):

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<StService>, string[]>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest,
                           opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Select(service => service.ServiceName)));
```

Comment: This works perfectly, Thank you!.  I was having issues with the .Select initially but then realized I needed to add the System.Linq using.

Just one additional question, I have a half dozen fields that need to be mapped this way.  Is there a way to do this more generically where it works for any field that is IEnumerable< Service> or do I need to map each specifically.